# Apache Trinidad <tr:convertNumber> component fails on Apache Tomcat v8+

Tags: tomcat, jsf, myfaces, trinidad

I am attempting to migrate an existing application with Apache Trinidad running on Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 and receiving the error below due to the usage of .

From what I can tell, Trinidad is on life support. The site is riddled with dead links and there has not been an update for 1/2 a year.

The original purpose of the Trinidad convertNumber component was to be more strict and throw a validation error if an invalid number was input i.e. `123.23.455`.

Questions:
1. Is Trinidad EOL or are there plans to update Trinidad to be compatible with the Tomcat 8 specs?
2. Does MyFaces impl of convertNumber provide the same validation as Trinidad's convertNumber component?

Convert Number Component:
`<tr:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="4" />`

Exception:

`Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:368)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:68)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:68)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:96)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.convert.ConvertNumberTag._setProperties(ConvertNumberTag.java:303)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.convert.ConvertNumberTag.createConverter(ConvertNumberTag.java:168)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadConverterELTag.doStartTag(TrinidadConverterELTag.java:68)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005fconvertNumber_005f0(page1_jspx.java:530)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005finputText_005f1(page1_jspx.java:497)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005fpanelPage_005f0(page1_jspx.java:397)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005fform_005f0(page1_jspx.java:356)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005fdocument_005f0(page1_jspx.java:237)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(page1_jspx.java:199)
    at org.apache.jsp.page1_jspx._jspService(page1_jspx.java:161)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    ... 50 more`

Comment: _"Does MyFaces impl of convertNumber provide the same validation as Trinidad's convertNumber component"_ Try...

Comment: @kukeltje - I did "try" before posting and it popped the same validation message as the Trinidad converter which caught me off guard, hence why I was hoping for confirmation.